# Serializing keys in JSON using Swift

Tags: json, swift

I am working on trying to serialize a JSON string. This one:

```
"user": {
    apellidos = "Vasco Fornas";
    "created_at" = "<null>";
    email = "m@gmail.com";
    "id_usuario" = 122;
    imagen = "1ufm2Fmifoto.jpeg";
    name = "";
    "nivel_usuario" = 1;
    nombre = Modesto;
    unidad = 0;
    "updated_at" = "<null>";
}, "uid": , "error": 0]
{
    apellidos = "Vasco Fornas";
    "created_at" = "<null>";
    email = "m@gmail.com";
    "id_usuario" = 122;
    imagen = "1ufm2Fmifoto.jpeg";
    name = "";
    "nivel_usuario" = 1;
    nombre = Modesto;
    unidad = 0;
    "updated_at" = "<null>";
}
```

And this is my code so far:

```
do {//creamos nuestro objeto json                
  print("recibimos respuesta")

  if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String:Any] { //Any for, Any data type

    //Do with json
    print(json);

    DispatchQueue.main.async {//proceso principal             
      let mensaje = json["user"]
      print(mensaje!);                      
    }
  }
}
```

The first print shows the complete JSON string, and the second print shows the item "user"

How could I get the values for all keys under "user" item?

Comment: The JSON looks odd. What is at root? Is user a key for an array of Dictionaries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this, eg:

```
if let mensaje = json["user"] as? [String:String] {
    for key in mensaje.keys {
        let currentValue = mensaje[key] as? String ?? "" // cast whatever you like
        print(currentValue)
    }
}
```

---

or getting values as array...

```
if let mensaje = json["user"] as? [String:String] {
    let yourValues = Array(mensaje.values)
    print(yourValues)
}
```

---

if you are searching for "apellidos":

```
var apellidos?
if let mensaje = (json["user"] as? [String:String]) {
    apellidos = mensaje["apellidos"] as? String ?? ""
}
print(apellidos)
```

Comment: thank you, it works. The only issue is that this way every key-value assignation is repeated for the number of keys times

Comment: I added another solution for getting in one shot all the values

Comment: and using your second option, how do I get the value for key "apellidos"?

Comment: added how to find "apellidos"

Comment: I suggests using SwiftyJSON

Comment: A JSON dictionary is always `[String:Any]` and **never** `[AnyHashable:Any]` because according to the specification all keys are required to be `String`